# How to convert java time to .net time in Android?

Tags: android, .net, time, gettime

I'm an Android developer and i'm having an issue about getting time with .Net "since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar)".

How can i convert java getTimeInMillis() to .Net time value?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //change your formate accordingly
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String inputString = "00:01:30.500";

Date date = sdf.parse("1970-01-01 " + inputString);
System.out.println("in milliseconds: " + date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank for answer my question :)
I made it works by add the milliseconds from 0001 year to 1970 to current milliseconds, then done